# is it possible to use usb wifi adapter in android emulator

Tags: android, windows, apk

I want to use Android TV Remote Control in my PC. I set up the android emulator bluestack, nox etc., but none of that working because there is no Wi-Fi in the emulator, even if I have the USB Wi-Fi adapter in my PC. Is it supposed to base on my PC? My PC has a Wi-Fi adapter, and the Android emulator has it too, because it runs on my PC.

Android TV Remote Control needs Wi-Fi to link with TV.

By the way, I have tried many solutions, but none have worked.
I want to know, is there another way to do this on PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better than Android TV Remote Control
https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy